# Binary Search Not Returning Last Value in Array

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I've been working on implementing a binary search function in C, and it seems to work in every case except in finding the last value in the array being searched. Would anyone please be so kind as to point me in the right direction. Thanks aplenty!

I realize this is likely some awful and inefficient code, (I'm only a few days in, forgive me!) so I'll be taking all of your guidance into consideration going forward.

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
int middle = (n / 2);
if (n < 0) 
{
    return false;
} 

if (n < 2 && n > 0) 
{
    if (value == values[0])
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
} 

const int MAX = 65536;
int half[MAX];

if (value > values[middle])
{
    int new_size = n - middle - 1;
    for (int i = 0, m = middle + 1; i < new_size; i++, m++)
    {
        half[i] = values[m];
    }
    return search(value, half, new_size);
    }

else if (value < values[middle])
{
    int new_size = n - middle;
    for (int i = 0, m = 0; i < middle; i++, m++)
    {
       half[i] = values[m];
    }
    return search(value, half, new_size);
}

else if (value == values[middle])
{
    return true;
}
return false;
}

void sort(int values[], int n)
{
int swap;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (values[j] > values[j + 1])
        {
            swap = values[j + 1];
            values[j + 1] = values [j];
            values[j] = swap;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This algorithm is very inefficient at best. Why do you need a new array every time? you could keep two pointers to the start and end of the array and change them as you would like!

Comment: Using a debugger is very helpful in such cases.

Comment: 1) `int new_size = n - middle;` --> `int new_size = middle;`

Comment: 2) `values[j] > values[j + 1]` : `values[j + 1]` might occurs out-of-bounds error.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY:  That should really be posted as an answer --- Rizwan Shirazi can't mark a comment accepted, so this question will remain "open".

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase I basically think debugging questions are off topics. You can make better answers by adding improvements of code instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sort function index out-of-bounds error might occur:
 Change inner for loop to :

```
for(j =0; j < n-1; j++)
```

what i interpret is that in your sort function you are trying to implement **Bubble** sort algorithm,it`s correct implementation is :

```
void sort(int a[], int n){
   int i,j,temp;
   for(i =0; i < n-1; i++){
     for(j =0; j < n-1-i; j++){
        if(a[j] > a[j+1]){
          temp = a[j];
          a[j] = a[j+1];
          a[j+1] = temp;
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for your guidance Amrender! Using your suggestion, along with debugging out loud, I was able to get the implementation working.

Comment: @RizwanShirazi if this answer is acceptable, than please mark it as accepted, else this question will remain open.